# Date submitted to REST API is incorrect in Salesforce

Tags: api, json, datetime

We have created a form in our website to submit info that will create a Lead in Salesforce.  Two of the Custom Fields we have are a Departure Date and Return Date.  We are submitting the date in the correct ISO 8601 format of yyyy-MM-dd and the API request is correct and the response back is successful. However, the values in the Lead in Salesforce when our team views it is that the date is a day earlier.

Example: 2017-09-15 submitted in the JSON request is showing up in the Salesforce Lead as 9/14/2017.

JSON String:

```
{
    "Agent_IATA__c": "00000000",
    "Agency_Name__c": "DEMO AGENCY",
    "FirstName": "TEST",
    "LastName": "TEST",
    "phone": "555-111-3311",
    "Email": "test@test.com",
    "Best_Time_To_Call__c": "Morning",
    "Time_Zone__c": "Pacific Time",
    "Lead_Passenger_Name__c": "DEMO TEST",
    "Number_Of_Adults__c": "4",
    "Number_Of_Children__c": "1",
    "Departure_Date__c": "2017-06-24",
    "Departure_City__c": "Philadelphia",
    "City1__c": "London",
    "City2__c": "Dublin",
    "City3__c": "",
    "City4__c": "",
    "City5__c": "",
    "Number_Of_Nights1__c": "4",
    "Number_Of_Nights2__c": "4",
    "Number_Of_Nights3__c": "",
    "Number_Of_Nights4__c": "",
    "Number_Of_Nights5__c": "",
    "Return_Date__c": "2017-07-05",
    "Return_From__c": "Dublin",
    "Hotel_Star_Rating__c": "4 Star",
    "Estimated_Total_Budget__c": "18000",
    "Feedback_Comments__c": "TEST",
    "Air_Needed__c": "Yes",
    "Class_of_Service__c": "Coach",
    "Travel_Between_Cities__c": "Car",
    "BussinessType__c": "FIT",
    "ImmediateBussiness__c": false,
    "RecordTypeId": "000000000000",
    "Web_Routing_Id__c": "Quote Request",
    "RefferingAgent__c": ""
}
```

We've also tried submitting the JSON request via and external app called POSTMAN and it also has the wrong date in Salesforce.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: did u check your salesforce  instance Default time zone in set up >  company information ?

Comment: Are `Departure Date` and `Return Date` for sure of the type `Date`? If they were `Datetime` you might get some time zone issues.

Comment: Can you please post the JSON string being sent, the TimeZone of the REST API user, and the TimeZone of the Org. This is most likely a timezone issue and the JSON string probably includes a time component

Comment: *"Don't worry about the world coming to an end today. It's already tomorrow in Australia." --Charles M. Schulz* ... If your integration user is GMT-0:00 or further East, then the dates are correct from a global perspective. Try setting your integration user to a Western time zone.

Comment: Our Default Time Zone is Pacific Standard Time, which is correct.  Both Dates are set up as Date/Time.  I believe, however, that we want it this way. I'll have to check with our managers to see if maybe we could change it to just Date. Integration User is also the same timezone as well.  I will include the JSON as well!

Comment: I've added the JSON string above.

Comment: @MichelleM - If the TZ is PST and the field is a Date Time, when submitted as in the JSON string ( a date only) it is interpreted as Midnight in the TZ of the authenticated user or GMT I forget which but it may be GMT, What is the time that is shown in SF along with the date? What is the TZ of the user Viewing the data?

Comment: @Eric The time that shows in SF is 09/14/2017 5:00pm when the date 09/15/2017 is submitted. The time zone of the viewers in SalesForce is PST.

Answer (score 1):

In our REST based services we have always passed the date values in the following format.

`"CommittedDate": "01/22/2017",
"RequestedDate": "02/02/2016"`

In the REST service we use the Date.Parse method to parse the date.

`Date dt = Date.Parse(CommittedDate);`

This seems to work with salesforce REST service.

Edit:

So I tried some code to use a time component.
This seems to work in execute anonymous.

```
string td = '01/01/2017 11:46 AM';
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(td);
System.Debug(dt);
```

Comment: Hello, our custom field is set up as a Date/Time, not Date, so just submitting "09/15/2017" is throwing a JSON error:  {
    "message": "Cannot deserialize instance of datetime from VALUE_STRING value 09/09/2017 or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:392]",
    "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
  }

Comment: @MichelleM Did you try the second part where I have passed the datetime string?

Comment: I did add the time to the formatted string yyyy-MM-dd and it successfully submitted correctly.  I used the local time of 5:00 AM and that submitted the correct date.